# Marge array values if two array values are match in two arrays

Tags: php, mysql

i have a two array when match the date then value are store in another array other wish date store and value blank. two array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 07/2016

    [1] => 08/2016

    [2] => 09/2016

    [3] => 10/2016

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 07/2016
            [1] => 124.19
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10/2016
            [1] => 248.38
        )
)
```

I want to get this type of out put.
array ( [0]=> Array ( [0] => 07/2016 [1] => 124.19 ) [1]=> Array ( [0]=> 08/2016 [1]=> ) [2]=> Array ( [0]=> 09/2016 [1]=> ) [3]=> Array ( [0]=> 10/2016 [1]=> 248.38 ) )

Comment: What is your desired output array?

Comment: For ex:
 array
 (
  [0]=> Array
   (
    [0] => 07/2016
    [1] => 124.19
   )
  [1]=> Array
   (
    [0]=> 08/2016
    [1]=>
   )
  [2]=> Array
   (
    [0]=>  09/2016
    [1]=>
   )
  [3]=> Array
   (
    [0]=>  10/2016
    [1]=> 248.38
   )
   
 )

Comment: Isn't that what you already got? Maybe you can format your edit to something readable?

Answer (score 0):

Since the expected output is a bit messy, here is my guess what you want.

Use array_column to get the dates in key 0 and match them with array1.
If it's a new item add it in array2.

https://3v4l.org/goh1D

```
$a1= Array(
0 => "07/2016",

1 => "08/2016",

2 => "09/2016",

3 => "10/2016",

);

$a2 =Array(
0 => Array
    (
        0 => "07/2016",
        1 => 124.19
    ),

1 => Array
    (
        0 => "10/2016",
        1 => 248.38
    )
);
// Grab dates from $a2 with array column
$column = array_column($a2, 0);

// Loop $a1 values 
Foreach($a1 as $val){
   // Is the $val not in array column? (New item)
   If(!in_array($val, $column)){
       $a2[][]=$val; // add new item in array
   }
}
Var_dump($a2);
```

Comment: @AKash don't dump it here. It's unreadable! Edit your post and add proper formatting to it